# Rails paper-trail associations based on versions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paper-trail-gem

I have a custom `versions` table with added columns for storing metadata. My question is simple: when I manually create a version with `widget.paper_trail.save_with_version` how can I pass in the metadata?

I tried using `info_for_paper_trail` but it gets called in every single action of the controller, and what's more it seems it is being called before `current_user` is defined.

This is the excerpt from my controller:

```
def mark_as_open
  update_status(:open, log: false, reset_approval_status: true) do
    if @servicing.redone
      update_redo_reason
      @servicing.paper_trail.save_with_version
    end
  end
end

def info_for_paper_trail
  {
    responsible_id: current_user.id,
    event_name: action_name,
  }
end
```

and this is my model:

```
has_paper_trail on: [], class_name: "ServicingVersion", meta: { technician_id: completed_by_id, area_id: area_id }
```

**EDIT:**

I believe this is a bug, and I created an issue on the [github repo](https://github.com/paper-trail-gem/paper_trail/issues/1124)